# Argument Null Exception when link pasted

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor web assembly application with a main page and a nested component:

```
@page "/work/{CustomerId:guid}"

@using System.Diagnostics
@using ApplySupportTool.Client.I18nText
@using ApplySupportTool.Client.Services.Contracts
@using ApplySupportTool.Shared.Dto.Customer
@using Toolbelt.Blazor.I18nText

@inject I18nText Localization
@inject ICustomerApi CustomerApi

@attribute [Authorize]


<h3>@string.Format(localizedStrings.WorkOverviewTitle, Customer?.CustomerName)</h3>

<MatTabGroup>
    <MatTab Label="@localizedStrings.TimeTrackingLabel">
        <CascadingValue Value="@CustomerId">
            <TimeTrackingList />
        </CascadingValue>
    </MatTab>

    <MatTab Label="@localizedStrings.WorkItemsLabel">
        Work Items
    </MatTab>
</MatTabGroup>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public CustomerDto Customer { get; set; }
    LocalizedStrings localizedStrings = new LocalizedStrings();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        localizedStrings = await Localization.GetTextTableAsync<LocalizedStrings>(this);
        Customer = await CustomerApi.GetCustomerByIdAsync(CustomerId);
    }
}
```

And the nested component:

```
@using ApplySupportTool.Client.I18nText
@using ApplySupportTool.Client.Components.Modals
@using ApplySupportTool.Client.Services.Contracts
@using Toolbelt.Blazor.I18nText

@inject I18nText Localization
@inject IModalService Modal
@inject ITimeTrackingApi TimeTrackingApi

@if (false)
{
    <LoadingDialog Title="@localizedStrings.LoadingLabel" IsOpen="true" />
} else
{
    <br />
    <MatButton Label="@localizedStrings.NewTimeTrackingLabel" Raised="true" OnClick="@OpenCreateTimeTrackingDialog" />

    <br />
    <br />

    ... 
    // Mat Blazor Accordion
}

@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    LocalizedStrings localizedStrings = new LocalizedStrings();

    public List<TimeTrackingDto> TimeTrackingDtoList = new List<TimeTrackingDto>();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        localizedStrings = await Localization.GetTextTableAsync<LocalizedStrings>(this);

        TimeTrackingDtoList = await TimeTrackingApi.GetTimeTrackingAsync(CustomerId);
    }   
}
```

This works as expected when I navigate through the browser. But when I copy the link it generates and paste it again to load the page I get a lot of wasm errors:

[image]

I checked the pages I have a string.format but couldn't find that there is something wrong. So I assume that it might be in parsing the parameter or something like that.

Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT1:
As suggested in the comments, I checked if the Guid is passed correctly. On the normal navigation it appears everywhere. But when I paste the link and navigate that way I only get it on the main page but it seems it isn't passed down to the nested component.
I also tried to change replace the Guid Type with a default string parameter. But that didn't change anything. Neither did replacing the cascading parameter with a normal parameter.

Comment: is this a thing with Url Decoding of the Guid into something that is not what you are expecting, console write  the CustomerID  before the line Customer = await CustomerApi.GetCustomerByIdAsync(CustomerId); does it match what you think you pasted into the Url

Comment: I checked for null, but VS already told me that a Guid can't ever be null. So it would have to be an empty Guid at least. So I assume that this happens even before that step.

Comment: Sorry I thing we are at cross purposes, I don't thing the Guid ids null I think it gets changed between being pasted into the address bar and arriving in the app. So when it tries to get the customer,  the customer is not found and that is what ends up being null.  I have had this happen with not Url Encoded guid's before.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try to verify that.

Comment: @DavidMasterson It seems to me that the issue is with the cascading parameter. I do get the parameter in the main page, but it seems like it fails to pass it further down.

Comment: Sorry, I think I sent you  on a wild goose chase, I see the problem now.

Comment: Mh, on further investigation: it seems that the issue has nothing to do with the nesting, but that the authorization is not persisted over the refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following code who shall display a dialog:

```
<MatDialog @bind-IsOpen="@deleteCustomerDialogOpen" Style="z-index: 100">
    <MatDialogTitle>
        <MatIcon Icon="warning" />@localizedStrings.ConfirmDeleteTitle
    </MatDialogTitle>
    <MatDialogContent>
        @string.Format(localizedStrings.DeleteCustomerConfirmationMessage, SelectedCustomerDto?.CustomerName)
    </MatDialogContent>
    <MatDialogActions>
        <MatButton OnClick="@DeleteCustomerAsync">@localizedStrings.DeleteLabel</MatButton>
        <MatButton OnClick="@(e => { deleteCustomerDialogOpen = false; })">@localizedStrings.CancelLabel</MatButton>
    </MatDialogActions>
</MatDialog>
```

And the localization is initialized as follows:
    LocalizedStrings localizedStrings = new LocalizedStrings();

```
/// <inheritdoc />
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    localizedStrings = await Localization.GetTextTableAsync<LocalizedStrings>(this);        
}
```

The issue seems to be, that on a reload the the string.format is executed before localizedStrings was properly loaded. Therefore this caused the issues. I changed the code to the following which fixed it:

```
@string.Format(localizedStrings.DeleteCustomerConfirmationMessage, SelectedCustomerDto?.CustomerName)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Child component

```
[Parameter]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
```

should be

```
[CascadingParameter]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Comment: You're right, my example code was wrong from a trial if it works when I navigate to the page directly. But unfortunately it doesn't work with the CascadinParameter.